# How can I Show a Modal-Form using Threading. C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am displaying a winForm using Application.Run(); in ShowForm() as shown below.

I am using ShowForm() with a thread in ShowSplash().

Im calling ShowSplash() in another Form,Lets say 'Form1'.
**How can I display it as Modal to Form1?**

```
static private void ShowForm()
    {
        splashForm = new frmWorking();
        Application.Run(splashForm);
    }

static public void ShowSplash()
{
Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(frmWorking.ShowForm));
thread.Start();           
}
```

Comment: There is such a thing as Google, C# Splash Screen... http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5454/A-Pretty-Good-Splash-Screen-in-C   http://crazorsharp.blogspot.co.uk/2009/06/creating-splash-screen-in-net-with.html

Comment: Actually,it is showing when My App is running.

Answer (score 2):

You can show modal form through ShowDialog method which expects instance of parent form. So you can provide instance of parent form (Form1 in your case).

eg.

splashForm.ShowDialog()